# Given 2 LINESTRINGs with common point, how to extract common point?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, line

I have 2 LINESTRING geometries. I know both share a common point. Using PostGIS for Postgres, what is the cleanest way to extract the common point?

Example with illustration:

[image: http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/images/st_touches05.png]

How do I extract the intersection of the green and blue line, assuming the points at the crossing are equal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [st_intersection](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html)

Examples 1:

```
test=# select st_astext(st_intersection('LINESTRING ( 0 0, 0 2 )'::geometry, 'LINESTRING ( 0 0, 2 0 )'::geometry));

 st_astext  
------------
 POINT(0 0)
(1 fila)
```

Example 2:

```
test=# select st_astext(st_intersection('LINESTRING ( 1 0,  0 2 )'::geometry, 'LINESTRING ( 0 0,  2 0 )'::geometry));
 st_astext  
------------
 POINT(1 0)
(1 fila)
```